# On submit of input, keyword being defaults to hexcode - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Upon the search, when you type in something such as 'blue', and press return, it states "Displaying palettes for "BLUE", but when you type 'blue' and press the search button, it defaults to 'FFFFFF', it's something to do with on submit and I can't figure it out,

When I remove 'color' class from the input:

```
 <input class=
            "search-input hex color {required:false}" id="nobg" name="hex"
            onchange=
            "document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color"
            placeholder="Enter hexcode or keyword (Eg, 'Blue')" type="search">
```

It fixes the issue, however that disables the colour picker (jscolor.js)

Upon press of the search input, it accepts and outputs hexcodes to the heading, however not keywords.

Can anybody suggest how to overcome this issue?

Here's [a link](http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00553636/hexactly/app.php) to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  'hex color' class on the input appears to want the input to be a hex value. The validator on the input must default to FFFFFF (white) if there is no valid hex number input. Type in 'blue' and hit Enter and you will see the POST value of hex is 'blue' not 0000FF. Are you searching on color names or hex values? If so, you can discard the color picker input and use a regular text input.

Since you are using jQuery already, why not ditch the entire form submit() and page refresh process and use $.ajax() to POST your query to a service that returns just the data you need? Then you can write the results to the page without refreshing. Check out Mustache or Handlebars for a templating engine to store and retrieve HTML templates for the results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am searching for both hex values and color names. Is there anyway I can remove the validator on the input from defaulting to FFFFFF if there is no valid hex number?

Comment: Try this, from the jscolor.com website: http://jscolor.com/try.php#tweaking. <input class="color {adjust:false}">